# how to rearrange the for loop and condition using list comprehension within one line?

Tags: python

This is the code so i want to optimise this code within one line using list comprehension how can i do this?

```
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
            'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
   
coded_word = []
var = 'hello'
for i in var:
    pos = alphabet.index(i) + 3
    if pos > 24 :
        pos %= 25
    coded_word.append(alphabet[pos])
    
coded_word
# ['k', 'h', 'o', 'o', 'r']
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for a list or a list comprehension. For efficiency use python string methods: a translation table with [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) and [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
alphabet2 = alphabet[3:]+alphabet[:3]
# 'defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabc'

trans = str.maketrans(alphabet, alphabet2)

var = 'hello'
var.translate(trans)
```

output: `'khoor'`